# PHP File count inside a folder

Tags: php

I'm using bootstrap tables and rows to count how much files are in a folder, but the destination is pointing to a different server the code below does not work.
As i'm using localhost (xampp) trying to do this don't know if its possible.

```
<?php 
// integer starts at 0 before counting
$i = 0; 
$dir = 'uploads/'; <!--\\189.207.00.122\folder1\folder2\folder3\test-->
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false){
if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..')) && !is_dir($dir.$file)) 
$i++;
}
}
// prints out how many were in the directory
echo "There were $i files";
?>
```

Comment: Well, the server might be rejecting your request, most servers should be. (Unless the "destination server" is your own).

Comment: The server is my own don't know if  i have to add the server address in my httpd file to allow access or $username $password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a handy little function you might want to try out. Just pass the `path to the Directory` as the first argument to it and you'd get your result.

**NOTE:** *This Function is RECURSIVE, which means: it will traverse all sub-directories... to disable this behaviour, simply comment out or delete the following lines towards the end of the Funciton:*

```
<?php
            }else if(is_dir($temp_file_or_dir) && !preg_match('/^\..*/', $val) ){
                getFilesInFolder($temp_file_or_dir);
            }
```

**THE CODE:**

```
<?php
    $folder = dirname(__FILE__).'/uploads';      // ASSUMES YOUR uploads DIRECTORY 
                                                 // IS IN THE SAME DIRECTORY AS index.php
                                                 // (/htdocs/php/pages)

    // OR
    $folder = dirname(__FILE__).'/../uploads';   // ASSUMES YOUR uploads DIRECTORY
                                                 // IS ONE DIRECTORY ABOVE
                                                 // THE CURRENT DIRECTORY (/htdocs/php)
                                                 // THIS IS MOST LIKELY RIGHT 
    // OR
    $folder = dirname(__FILE__).'/../../uploads';// ASSUMES YOUR uploads DIRECTORY
                                                 // IS TWO DIRECTORIES ABOVE
                                                 // THE CURRENT DIRECTORY (/htdocs)

    // MAKE SURE THE FOLDER IN QUESTION HAS THE RIGHT PERMISSIONS
    // OR RATHER CHANGE PERMISSIONS ON THE FOLDER TO BE ABLE TO WORK WITH IT
    chmod($folder, 0777);

    var_dump(getFilesInFolder($folder));


    // IF YOU PASS false AS THE THE 2ND ARGUMENT TO THIS FUNCTION
    // YOU'D GET AN ARRAY OF ALL FILES IN THE $path2Folder DIRECTORY
    // AS WELL AS IN SUB-DIRECTORIES WITHIN IT...
    function getFilesInFolder($path2Folder, $countOnly=true){
        $files_in_dir   = scandir($path2Folder);
        $returnable     = array();

        foreach($files_in_dir as $key=>$val){
            $temp_file_or_dir = $path2Folder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $val;
            if(is_file($temp_file_or_dir) && !preg_match("#^\..*#", $temp_file_or_dir)){
                $arrRX                  = array('#\.{2,4}$#', '#\.#');
                $arrReplace             = array("", "_");
                $returnVal              = preg_replace($arrRX, $arrReplace, $val);
                $returnable[$returnVal] = $temp_file_or_dir;
            }else if(is_dir($temp_file_or_dir) && !preg_match('/^\..*/', $val) ){
                getFilesInFolder($temp_file_or_dir);
            }
        }
        return ($countOnly) ? count($returnable) : $returnable;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to get your root directory.

```
$dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/';
```

Comment: This is the error im getting.Warning: opendir(C:/xampp/htdocs/uploads/,C:/xampp/htdocs/uploads/): The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2) in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\pages\index.php on line 410

Warning: opendir(C:/xampp/htdocs/uploads/): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\pages\index.php on line 410
There were 0 files

Comment: What is the directory of the folder from htdocs you want to find?

Comment: This is how I'm entering the code to check the following directory  $dir = $_SERVER['http://204.123.70.4'].'\\test\test1\test2'; then check whats inside that's folder.